# How to use a class builder with optional parameter?

Tags: java

I am building my own APIResponse class and one of the columns is Optional with any type of DTO/type of variable or null but I am always getting error `Cannot infer type arguments for APIResponse<>`.

What I want is to pass an Optional of **ANY TYPE**

APIResponse.java

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class APIResponse<T> {

    private String message;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private Optional<T> data;

}
```

Below is how I tried to use the APIReponse:

```
// Create an APIResponse object with null data
// Not sure why <String> does not return an error
// <String>, <Integer>, etc does not return any error
APIResponse<String> responseWithNullData = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, null);

// Create an APIResponse object with string data
// error Cannot infer type arguments for APIResponse<>
APIResponse<String> responseWithData = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, "HEY");

// Create an APIResponse object with string data
// error Cannot infer type arguments for APIResponse<>
APIResponse<Optional<String>> responseOptionalString = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, "Optinal HEY");

// Create an APIResponse object with custom class DTO
// error Cannot infer type arguments for APIResponse<>
APIResponse<CustomDTO> apiResponse = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, this.customDTO);
```

If it matters, I am using spring boot (If you can recommend me a better approach for my concern, that would be great)

Comment: What is `this.customDTO`?

Comment: Why are you passing a string instead of `Optional<String>`?

Comment: Just plain DTO (Data transfer object). fields can be messages, user info, etc.

Comment: <String> or <Optional<String>> still give the same error.

Comment: If you want a `APIResponse<String>`, you need to pass it an `Optional<String>` in the constructor.

Comment: Added lombok AllArgsContructor or manually added the optional constructor has the same error message.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say. The problem is very straightfoward. It's expecting one argument type and you're passing another.

Comment: `"HEY"` is a `String`, not an `Optional<String>`.

Comment: Yeah I think I need to clarify my question. brb.

Comment: If you want an Optional of any type, you can get rid of `T` and accept `Optional<?>` instead. But again, you're not passing an Optional at all.

Comment: Yeah I think that was the issue. My class was expecting an Optional of anything but I am passing strictly String or CustomDTO. @subasri_'s answer was what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the variable `data` is of type `Optional<T>`, the same has to be passed while initializing the object as well

```
APIResponse<String> responseWithData = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, Optional.of("HEY"));

APIResponse<CustomDTO> apiResponse = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, Optional.of(this.customDTO));
```

Having said that, there are also a couple of variations you could do if it applies to your use case

Declaring variable `data` of type `T` and not as Optional, i.e.

```
public class APIResponse<T> {
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private T data;
}

APIResponse<String> responseWithData = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, "HEY");

APIResponse<CustomDTO> apiResponse = new APIResponse<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK, this.customDTO);
```

Or you could avoid using the generic type `T` and use the wildcard `?` which represents the unknown type (as discussed in the comments)

```
public class APIResponse {
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private Optional<?> data;
}

APIResponse responseWithData = new APIResponse("Success", HttpStatus.OK, Optional.of("HEY"));

APIResponse apiResponse = new APIResponse("Success", HttpStatus.OK, Optional.of(this.customDTO));
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This is what I needed. I was passing String instead of Optional<String>..

Comment: can you check if passing it Optional.empty() when your builder is accepting T works? @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: @experimentunit1998X yeah `Optional.empty()` also works if you want to pass null values exclusively. But for me, I want to use the `Optional.of(TYPE)` instead

Comment: I was referring to if your message of type T (any random type you want) would accept Optional.empty(). It seems it doesn't which would mean that rather than T, it might be better to use ? wild card as shmosel suggested.

Comment: It does accept `Optional.empty()` even if I use `<T>`. Since I am still new to Java and Spring boot, I cant really judge which is the better approach. For now I will use @shmosel's suggestion to use `<?>`

Comment: What I did was `public class APIResponse<T>` then `private Optional<?> data;`. If I do `?` in my `public class`, it will generate errors . Is this approach correct?

Comment: I think it should be fine. though I m just doing this to check something out, my grasp of generics isnt that in depth. Maybe you could ask shmosel?

Comment: I've updated my answer on the other variations as well

Comment: @subasri_. Thank you for updating your answer. However, the 2nd answer was my original code that did not work thus me asking here in the first place. Since I am also trying to pass a null param. For the 3rd answer,  it does work using wildcard. also makes the code cleaner too.